# using checkboxes to change state and sort list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list like this:

```
<div className="doubleCol">
    {this.state.symptoms.map(item => (
        <ListItem key={item.ObjectID}>
            <input type="checkbox" className="sympSelect" />
            {item.name}
        </ListItem>
     ))}
</div>
```

All the items rendered have checkbox and I want it to filter a different list elsewhere on the page based on which boxes are checked. To do that I need the checkboxes to change the state and pass the new state to a method which is supposed to filter and display only those items on the second list with id's associated to items on the first list.

From what I have read it shouldn't matter for this purpose if the checkboxes are controlled or uncontrolled.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
        conditions: [],
        symptoms: [],
        selectedSymptom: []
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getConditionsMethod();
        this.getSymptomsMethod();
    }

    getConditionsMethod = () => {
        API.getConditions()
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                data.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
                this.setState({
                    conditions: data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };

    filterConditionsMethod = () => {
        API.getConditions()
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                data.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
                this.setState({
                    selectedSymptom: data.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    };
```

But I am kind of stuck on how to structure the onChange for when the box is checked and how to make that implement the filter.

Comment: Is there any reason why you dont want the checkboxes to be controled? You could add an `onChange` on the checkboxes and then update the state of  your `symptoms`-arrray, but then you would just make the checkboxes both, kind of, controled and uncontroled, and I cant see why you would want that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is you solution you can add onChange event for checkbox and filter your records as selectedSymptoms and symptoms. Please check code is

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      conditions: [],
      symptoms: [
        { ObjectID: 1, name: "xyz" },
        { ObjectID: 2, name: "pqr" }
      ],
      selectedSymptom: [],
      checked: ""
    };
  }

  updateCheckBox = (event, item) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      let selectedList = this.state.selectedSymptom;
      selectedList.push(item);
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        checked: this.state.checked == "checked" ? "" : "checked",
        selectedSymptom: selectedList
      });
    } else {
      const symptomss = this.state.selectedSymptom.filter(element => {
        if (element.ObjectID != data.ObjectID) {
          return item;
        }
      });
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        checked: "",
        selectedSymptom: symptomss
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="doubleCol">
        {this.state.symptoms.map(item => (
          <ListItem key={item.ObjectID}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              className="sympSelect"
              onChange={this.updateCheckBox(e, item)}
              id="symptoms_id"
              defaultChecked={this.state.checked}
            />
            {item.name}
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```